# How to count the number of categorical features with Pandas?

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, dtype

I have a `pd.DataFrame` which contains different dtypes columns. I would like to have the count of columns of each type. I use Pandas 0.24.2.

I tried:

```
    dataframe.dtypes.value_counts()
```

It worked fine for other `dtypes (float64, object, int64)` but for a weird reason, it doesn't aggregate the 'category' features, and I get a different count for each category (as if they would be counted as different values of dtypes).

I also tried:

```
    dataframe.dtypes.groupby(by=dataframe.dtypes).agg(['count'])
```

But that raises a

> TypeError: data type not understood.

Reproductible example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A','a',1,10], ['B','b',2,20], ['C','c',3,30]], columns = ['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4'])

df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].astype('category')
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].astype('category')

print(df.dtypes.value_counts())
```

Expected result:

```
    int64       2
    category    2
    dtype: int64
```

Actual result:

```
    int64       2
    category    1
    category    1
    dtype: int64
```

Comment: It looks like a bug :(, `value_counts()` works perfectly for every other dtypes except `category`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah What's your version, it works for me with 0.19.2

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Oh bug for 0.25.0

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.get_dtype_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get_dtype_counts.html):

```
print (df.get_dtype_counts())
category    2
int64       2
dtype: int64
```

But if use last version of pandas your solution is recommended:

> Deprecated since version 0.25.0.
>
> Use .dtypes.value_counts() instead.

Answer (score 5):

As @jezrael mentioned that it is deprecated in 0.25.0, `dtypes.value_counts(0)` would give two `category`ies, so to fix it do:

```
print(df.dtypes.astype(str).value_counts())
```

Output:

```
int64       2
category    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That is strange, any idea why?

Comment: @anky_91 Who knows?

Comment: @anky_91 I found a github pandas bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8559